# check box validation based on value in drop box

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to add additional options by automatically checking the check box based on the value selected in the dropbox for each entry.
When i give a if condition in the page_load it is not working but if i directly pass the value as false , the check box is unchecked.

Previously for all the values in the particular dropdown the check box will be ticked , but now i want the checkbox to be left checked for a particular single value.ddlBrand is the ID of the dropbox

```
if (ddlBrand.SelectedValue == "xyz")
 {
  chkGHS.Checked = false;
 }//not working


 chkGHS.Checked = false;// working
```

When a particular value is selected (It will be automatically brought up when the entry number is given), the check box should be unticked for rest of the values it should be ticked by default

Comment: Show your .aspx code as well, and why are you trying this on Page_Load?

Comment: aspx code of the check box :                                 <asp:CheckBox ID="chkGHS" Text="Include Language Label" runat="server" CssClass="label_text"
                                    Checked="true" />

Comment: @jawaf Anwar : i am going it in the page_load is because the dropdown value changes based on the entry that the user is selecting , if the select some other entry the check box should be checked,that why!

Comment: Edit your question with your DropDown Code as well, and you don't need to put that on Page_Load event, there is another way to achieve it, you have to provide an event to DropDown `SelectedIndexChanged` and set `AutoPostBack="true"` and you'll achieve the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

You should **debug** it, may be your **dropdown** selected value is not match with **xyz**. Otherwise code is ok.